# Global variables that mix between servers, python discord

Tags: python, global-variables, global, discord, discord.py

I have a game that is basically two commands, **test** and **test2**.
**test** makes you generate a word that you have to guess in **test2**, and if you miss the word 6 times you lose.

```
from collections import defaultdict

word = ""
guessesLeft = 6
blanks = []
guessedLetters = []
lettersFound = 0

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("!"))

bot.gamex = defaultdict(bool)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message):

    await ctx.message.delete()

    global word, guessesLeft, blanks, lettersFound, guessedLetters
    if not bot.gamex[ctx.guild.id]:

        word = message.lower()

        blanks = []
        guessedLetters = []
        lettersFound = 0
        guessesLeft = 6

        bot.gamex[ctx.guild.id] = True

        for i in range(0, len(word)):
            blanks .append("-")
        print(i)

        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="hangman:  " + " ".join(blanks)))

@bot.command()
async def test2(ctx, *, guess):

    global word, guessesLeft, blanks, lettersFound, guessedLetters

    if bot.gamex[ctx.guild.id]:
        if str.isalpha(guess) and len(guess) is 1 and str.lower(guess) not in guessedLetters:
            if str.lower(guess) in word:
                await ctx.send(guess + " is in the word.  Good job!")
                for i in range(0, len(word)):
                    if word[i] == str.lower(guess):
                        blanks[i] = str.lower(guess)
                        lettersFound += 1

            else:
                await ctx.send(guess + " is NOT in the word.")
                guessesLeft -= 1

            guessedLetters.append(str.lower(guess))
            await ctx.send(" ".join(blanks))
            await ctx.send("Guessed letters: " + " ".join(guessedLetters))
            await ctx.send("Guesses left: " + str(guessesLeft))

            if guessesLeft == 0:
                await ctx.send("No guesses left.  You lose!")
                bot.gamex[ctx.guild.id] = False
            if lettersFound == len(word)-1:
                await ctx.send("You've won!  The word was: " + word)
                bot.gamex[ctx.guild.id] = False
```

It's a hangman game, but the game variables are mixing on every server the bot is on, if I guess a word on one server, it appears on another server, I want each server to be individual and have commands individual.
Only those in the global are mixing. 
What would the command look like so that the variables don't get mixed up between the servers?

Comment: Don't use global variables.  Instead create a `Game` class that stores the state of a particular game, then create a dictionary that maps guild ids to `Game` instances

Comment: Can you explain your problem in other words. The usage or the words "server", "bot", "mixing" are so unclear.

Comment: @MohammadElAssal The word and other variables stored on one server appear on the other servers, all these variables: word, guessesLeft, blanks, guessedLetters, lettersFound.

Comment: How do I do these instances? @PatrickHaugh

Comment: How are the servers connected?

Comment: @MohammadElAssal the bot are in more than 10 servers

Comment: the word, guessesLeft, blanks, guessedLetters, lettersFound variables that are used by the commands on one server will appear on the other server, I wish each server was unique, and each could play the game without interference

Comment: do you know anything about OOP. like classes and instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class that represents the state of the game, and replace your `gamex` mapping with a mapping of guild ids to games:

```
games = {}

class Game:
    def __init__(self, word, guesses=6):
        self.word = word.lower()
        self.blanks = ["-"]*len(word)
        self.guessedLetters = []
        self.lettersFound = 0
        self.guessesLeft = guesses
```

Then in your commands, you get the `Game` storing the state for that guild.

```
@bot.command()
async def create_game(ctx, *, word):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if ctx.guild.id in games:
        await ctx.send("Game already in progress")
    else:
        games[ctx.guild.id] = Game(word)
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="hangman:  " + " ".join(games[ctx.guild.id].blanks)))
```

And you would call `del games[ctx.guild.id]` to remove entries when the game is complete.

A well-designed `Game` object would mean that the logic about how the game is played would be pulled out of your commands and into the `Game` object.  Ideally, you would be able to take the `Game` class from this code and use it to implement the same game in a browser or other interface with minimal changes.

Comment: games[ctx.guild.id].blanks dont show the words with "-", dont get nothing.
I need to use @commands.command() instead of @bot.command(), but how can I will call a variable guessedLetters in another @commands.command() ?

Comment: Do you see an error?  If not, then `games[ctx.guild.id].blanks` refers to some value.  What is it?  The `games` dictionary needs to exist outside of the scope of the commands, so that it shared between the commands.  If you're using cogs you can make it an attribute of the cog.